# Unable to view ,ipynb files in the folder when opened in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have recently installed jupyter and the bug I am facing that when I open a folder in the terminal and when jupyter opens, it is showing me the folders in the directory but the files in those folders are not being displayes and show that the folder is empty although opening the folder there files ipynb do exist.

For example,

I open Python-Data-Science-and-Machine-Learning-Bootcamp through the terminal in the jupyter and in it there are

Deep Learning
...

which have .ipynb files but opening the folder in jupyter shows the folder is empty

[image: normal file explorer]
[image: Opening jupyter notebook]
[image: in the terminal]

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: With an open Jupyter notebook, in a code cell, check your working directory with `!pwd` command and show us the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the problem. Weirldy, it was because the name of the file had something weird going on with it when I downloaded it. It is working fine after I completely renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook usually doesn't detect .ipynb files if the file path is too long. It starts cribbing that "The file name or extension is too long"

**Possible solutions:**

1. Don't have many sub folders from the root folder where jupyter notebook opens from.
2. Copy it(.ipynb file) into folder where ipnyb file are read earlier successfully and try.

It's better to set your working directory as close to the target csv file as possible.